# How to reposition non reliative multiple labels of edges in JGraphX

Tags: jgraphx

In a graph, I have edges that have more than one label (multi labels): one label is beside the source cell and another one beside the target cell. Both labels are created as child vertices of the edge. For correct positioning adjustement reasons, these labels do not have their geometry set relative (to the edge). When generating the edges, labels are correctly positionned: I use the `mxGraphView.getPerimeterPoint()` and an few adjustements to position the source and target labels.

When moving a cell using the mouse drag, I need to reposition these labels. For the moment I have tried to react to graph events (`mxEvent.CELLS_MOVED`, `mxEvent.MOVE_CELLS`) or model events (`mxEvent.CHANGE`) registering either a graph or a model listener.

However, the `getPerimeterPoint` function uses an `mxCellState` (not an `mxCell`) obtained through the graphView (`graph.getView().getState(cell)`) to do the calculation and this cell state mxGeometry is based on the previous position of the cell.

- Is this solution based on events the correct way of doing this?
- And if yes, should I rewrite completely the getPerimeterPoint (and functions used in it) to use the mxCell returned by the event (`event.getProperties("cells")`) whose greometry is correct rather than the `mxCellState`? Or is there a technique to get the cell state corresponding to the end of the current move operation without messing up the whole graph update process?

Any help or advice appreciated, thanks.